# java animation trouble getting the x and y cordinates of the mouse

Tags: java, swing, animation, actionlistener, java-2d

so i wrote this code but im not sure of where does the mouse listener goes and also how to loop the program.
im trying to achieve a particle explosion passing the x and y coordinates of the mouse when it's clicked. also i want to loop it till the program closes but i cant figure it out. so far all i got is one explosion 
the main class (frame)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class AnimationOfExplosingSquares extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
private int x;
private int y;
AnimationOfExplosingSquares(){

     add(new ExplosingSquares(x,y));

       setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public static void main (String[] args){
 AnimationOfExplosingSquares frame = new  AnimationOfExplosingSquares();
frame.setTitle("Squares");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1280, 800);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    while(x>0){
    this.x=me.getX();
    this.y=me.getX();
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

the ExplosingSquares class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class ExplosingSquares extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{
private int x;
private int y;
  private Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);


private ArrayList<Square> squares=new ArrayList<Square>();


ExplosingSquares(int x,int y){ 
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;


  for(int i=0; i<100;i++){


 Square squ = new Square(x,y);

    squares.add(squ);
  }
  timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){

super.paintComponent( g );

for( Square square : squares )    {

    square.boom();

g.setColor( square.getColor() );
 // update the square's location 
    g.fillRect( square.getXCoord(), square.getYCoord(),(int)square.getSize(), (int)square.getSize());

}
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    repaint();
}
}
```

the Square class

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.util.Random;


  class Square {

   private int width;
    private int height;
    //direction of x cordinate
    private Random random= new Random();
  private   int randomNumber=(random.nextInt(25)-12);
     //direction of y cordinate
   private  Random rand= new Random();
private     int rando=(rand.nextInt(25)-12);



private int x;
    private int y;
    private double size=50;
    Color c=new Color((int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256),(int)(Math.random()*256)); 

     Square(){


     }
     Square(int width, int height){
         this.width=width;
         this.height=height;      

     }
      Square(int width, int height,Color c){
         this.width=width;
         this.height=height;
         this.c=c;


     }
     public void setWidth(int width){
         this.width=width;
     }
     public void setHeight(int height){
         this.height=height;
     }
      public void setSize(double size){
         this.size=size;
     }
       public void setColor(Color c){
         this.c=c;
     }
     public int getXCoord() {
      return x+width;

     }
     public int getYCoord(){
      return y+height;
      }

       public double getSize(){
        return size;
    }
     public double getHeight(){
        return size;
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return c;
    }


       public void boom(){
        this.x+=rando;
        this.y+=randomNumber;
        this.size-=1;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Debugging is an important skill you absolutely must develop...

Answer (score 1):

Swing uses a single thread for painting and event handling.  Anything that blocks this thread from executing, will prevent the event dispatch thread form processing repaint requests.

The `while` loop in the mouseClicked event will stop your program from running.

I suggest you use a javax.swing.Timer instead. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.getY()` if you need the y position.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    while(x>0){
    this.x=me.getX();
    this.y=me.getY();
    }
}
```